# solve.QP - Constraints are Inconsistent

Tags: r

I am attempting to use solve.QP to solve a quadratic program where there are three constraints:

- All sum to 1 (this works fine)
- All must be greater than 0 (this works fine as well)
- All must be less than .30 (this is what is not working)

First, the test data:

```
n <- 6
r <- array(rnorm(n^2, mean=1), c(100,n)) # the 'returns'
colnames(r) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
```

My function:

```
eff.frontier <- function (returns, short="no", max.allocation=NULL, risk.premium.up=.5, risk.increment=.005){     
  covariance <- cov(returns)
  n <- ncol(covariance)
  Amat <- matrix (1, nrow=n)
  bvec <- 1
  meq <- 1
  if(short=="no"){
    Amat <- cbind(1, diag(n))
    bvec <- c(bvec, rep(0, n))
  }
  if(!is.null(max.allocation)){
    if(max.allocation > 1 | max.allocation <0){
      stop("max.allocation must be greater than 0 and less than 1")
    }
    Amat <- cbind(Amat, -1*diag(n))
    # This seems to be the issue area....
    bvec <- c(bvec, rep(-max.allocation, n))
    print(bvec)
  }
  loops <- risk.premium.up / risk.increment + 1
  loop <- 1
  #Initialize a matrix to contain allocation and statistics
  eff <- matrix(nrow=loops, ncol=n+3)
  # Now I need to give the matrix column names
  colnames(eff) <- c(colnames(returns), "Std.Dev", "Exp.Return", "sharpe")
  # Loop through the quadratic program solver
  for (i in seq(from=0, to=risk.premium.up, by=risk.increment)){
    dvec <- colMeans(returns) * i
    sol <- solve.QP(covariance, dvec=dvec, Amat=Amat, bvec=bvec, meq=meq)
    eff[loop,"Std.Dev"] <- sqrt(sum(sol$solution *colSums((covariance * sol$solution))))
    eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] <- as.numeric(sol$solution %*% colMeans(returns))
    eff[loop,"sharpe"] <- eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] / eff[loop,"Std.Dev"]
    eff[loop,1:n] <- sol$solution
    loop <- loop+1
  }
  return(as.data.frame(eff))
}
```

When I don't try to set an allocation maximum, this works fine.  But no matter what I try to set as the max.allocation, it always fails.

Am I setting up the Amat or bvec incorrectly?

Here is the error:

```
> eff <- eff.frontier(returns=r, short="yes", risk.premium.up=.5, risk.increment=.001, max.allocation=.15)
     Error in solve.QP(covariance, dvec = dvec, Amat = Amat, bvec = bvec, meq = meq) : 
  constraints are inconsistent, no solution!
```

Here is the Amat:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1   -1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0   -1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0   -1    0    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0   -1    0    0
[5,]    1    0    0    0    0   -1    0
[6,]    1    0    0    0    0    0   -1
```

And here is the bvec:

```
[1]  1.00 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15
```

How are these inconsistent??

Thank you,

Andrew

Comment: There are 6 assets, each with at most 15% of the portfolio: you can reach at most 6*15%=90% -- the weights cannot sum up to 100%... You apparently intended to set `max.allocation` to `.30`.

Comment: Jeez....  I can't believe that.  I've been staring at this and never checked how many assets there are.

Comment: Vincent--Thank You!  Just goes to show that sometimes you need to step away from the keyboard.

Comment: can someone help me ? Many thanks <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327206/portfolio-optimization-solve-qp-inequality-constraints>